# Como criar um formulário de cadastro com Django

Tags: python, django

recentemente venho estudando Django, mas me deparei com um problema em criar formulários, já tentei ir na documentação oficial do Framework mas não encontrei a solução.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Novo_Usuario

class FormNovoUsuario(forms.Form):

    nome = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label='nome')
    sobrenome = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label='sobrenome')
    senha = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='senha')


    class Meta:
        fields = ('nome', 'sobrenome', 'senha')
        models = Novo_Usuario
```

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Novo_Usuario(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

**views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Novo_Usuario
from .forms import FormNovoUsuario

def cms(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')

def cad_novo_usuario(request):
    form = FormNovoUsuario(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return form.save()
    return render(request, 'novo_usuario.html', {'form': form})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual problema você encontrou? Explique melhor onde você está com dificuldade

Comment: Talvez o erro seja no atributo save(), pois o erro que recebo é 'FormNovoUsuario' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 1):

O teu formulário não está associado ao modelo, daí ele não herdou de lugar algum o atributo "save". Aqui você tem duas formas de corrigir isto, no primeiro remova a sub classe `Meta` do formulário (ela não está sendo utilizada) e edite o método `cad_novo_usuario()` para algo mais ou menos assim:

```
    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        novo_usuario = model.Novo_Usuario()
        novo_usuario.nome = form..cleaned_data('nome')
        # ... daí um para cada campo que você tiver ...
        novo_usuario.save()
    return form.save()
```

Ou, então, você pode usar o formulário baseado em um modelo. Daí altere a classe do formulário para:

```
class FormNovoUsuario(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('nome', 'sobrenome', 'senha')
        model = Novo_Usuario
```

E no método `cad_novo_usuario()` faça:

```
    # ...
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid:
        form.save()
```